# Deleting unnecessary lines within log files using Python

Tags: python, file, logging, directory

I have log files being generated that have a lot of information in them.  They are beginning to take up a lot of space on the servers. Right now these logs are necessary, but a lot of the information isn't! Can someone help me write a python script that deletes all lines that contain "[TRACE]" in all of the log files in the folder. Thank you!

Comment: I would say using python for this is overkill. If you're on Linux - use sed:

sed '/[TRACE]/d' filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (assuming that you can load a complete log file into memory) is this one-liner which can be directly executed in a python interpreter:

```
open('trimmed.log', 'w+').writelines([l for l in open('original.log').readlines() if '[TRACE]' not in l])
```

You will have to manually change the name of your input file ('original.log') and eventually the output file ('trimmed.log') as well.

A step further would be a function like this (so that you can call it within a loop for all your files):

```
def filter_logs(log_path, target_string='[TRACE]'):
    with open(log_path) as infile:
        with open(log_path + '.notrace.log', 'w+') as ofile:
            for log_line in infile.readlines():
                if target_string not in log_line:
                    ofile.write(log_line)
```

File handlers are being taken care of explicitly (hence the two "with" statements) and as I said before, it lets you pass a path to your log file and even change the string you want to compare if you want to delete lines containing some other string. It will write a file next to your original log but with the suffix '.notrace.log' (make sure you have writing permissions there).

Happy trimming!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as an overkill to use Python for such task

**solution (Linux)**

```
sed '/[TRACE]/d' filename.txt | tee filename.txt
```

*Result*

```
[~]% cat filename.txt 
[TRACE] not needed
needed
needed2
not needed again [TRACE]

[~]% sed '/[TRACE]/d' filename.txt | tee filename.txt

[~]% cat filename.txt                                
needed
needed2
```

you can run this on schedule and it works super fast

Comment: You need to escape the `[]`, otherwise you will delete lines like `NEEDED`.